# Generating a .ov2 file with Java

Tags: java, php, tomtom

I am trying to figure out how to create a .ov2 file to add POI data to a TomTom GPS device.  The format of the data needs to be as follow:

An OV2 file consists of POI records. Each record has the following data format.

- 1 BYTE, char, POI status ('0' or '2')
- 4 BYTES, long, denotes length of the POI record.
- 4 BYTES, long, longitude * 100000
- 4 BYTES, long, latitude * 100000
- x BYTES, string, label for POI, x =3D=3D total length =96 (1 + 3 * 4)
- Terminating null byte.

I found the following PHP code that is supposed to take a .csv file, go through it line by line, split each record and then write it into a new file in the proper format.  I was hoping someone would be able to help me translate this to Java.  I really only need the line I marked with the '--->' arrow.  I do not know PHP at all, but everything other than that one line is basic enough that I can look at it and translate it, but I do not know what the PHP functions are doing on that one line.  Even if someone could explain it well enough then maybe I could figure it out in Java.  If you can translate it directly, please do, but even an explanation would be helpful.  Thanks.

```
<?php 
$csv = file("File.csv"); 
$nbcsv = count($csv); 
$file = "POI.ov2"; 
$fp = fopen($file, "w"); 
for ($i = 0; $i < $nbcsv; $i++) { 
    $table = split(",", chop($csv[$i])); 
    $lon = $table[0]; 
    $lat = $table[1]; 
    $des = $table[2]; 
    --->$TT = chr(0x02).pack("V",strlen($des)+14).pack("V",round($lon*100000)).pack("V",round($lat*100000)).$des.chr(0x00); 
    @fwrite($fp, "$TT"); 
} 
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: Have you done a google search on what those methods do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load a file into an array, where each element is a line from the file.

```
$csv = file("File.csv");
```

Count the number of elements in the array.

```
$nbcsv = count($csv);
```

Open output file for writing.

```
$file = "POI.ov2"; 
$fp = fopen($file, "w");
```

While `$i` < number of array items, `$i++`

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $nbcsv; $i++) {
```

Right trim the line (remove all whitespace), and split the string by ','. `$table` is an array of values from the csv line.

```
    $table = split(",", chop($csv[$i]));
```

Assign component parts of the table to their own variables by numeric index.

```
    $lon = $table[0]; 
    $lat = $table[1]; 
    $des = $table[2];
```

The tricky bit.

chr(02) is literally character code number 2.
`pack` is a binary processing function. It takes a format and some data.
`V` = unsigned long (always 32 bit, [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) byte order).

I'm sure you can work out the maths bits, but you need to convert them into [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) order 32 bit values.

`.` is a string concat operator.

Finally it is terminated with chr(0). Null char.

```
$TT = chr(0x02).
  pack("V",strlen($des)+14).
  pack("V",round($lon*100000)).
  pack("V",round($lat*100000)).
  $des.chr(0x00);
```

Write it out and close the file.

```
    @fwrite($fp, "$TT"); 
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is absolutely wonderful.  I had an idea that the pack function was something like that, but I was totally confused with the dot `.` notation being used to concatinate strings.  I am so used to the `.` being used to call a method or function.  When I saw that I was thinking it was somehow calling the pack function recursively instead of sequentially. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @kei23th FYI, PHP's "object operator" (its equivalent of Java's `.`) is `->`. `+` in PHP does arithmetic addition and calculates array co-efficients but produces potentially odd results when used on strings, because it tries to convert them to numbers (PHP is *extremely* promiscuously typed) and perform an arithmetic addition. Most of the time the result of this will be `int(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The key in JAVA is to apply proper byte order ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN to the ByteBuffer.

The whole function:

```
private static boolean getWaypoints(ArrayList<Waypoint> geopoints, File f)
{
try{
FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream(f);

for (int i=0;i<geopoints.size();i++)
{

     fs.write((byte)0x02);
     String desc = geopoints.get(i).getName();

     int poiLength = desc.toString().length()+14;
     fs.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(poiLength).array());

     int lon = (int)Math.round((geopoints.get(i).getLongitudeE6()/1E6)*100000);
     fs.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(lon).array());        

     int lat = (int)Math.round((geopoints.get(i).getLatitudeE6()/1E6)*100000);
     fs.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).putInt(lat).array());


     fs.write(desc.toString().getBytes());

     fs.write((byte)0x00);

}


    fs.close();

    return true;

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return false;
}


}
```